# JQuery function apparently auto-running / event triggered automatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to have a 2 option when someone enter the website: One for *register* and other for *enter / log-in.*

I've made 2 buttons, created a function that allows the form / inputs to fade in.

But it keeps fading in without the pressing of the button when I refresh / enter the page.

```
 function opc(){
            $("#form").hide().fadeIn(1000);}

    $("#registar").click(opc());
    $("#entrar").click(opc());
```

This is the only JavaScript / JQuery I've written so far. #form is already with **Display:none** from the styles.

You can see the "website" in action [here](http://79.170.43.200/joaorochahostingpackage.com/mydiary/).

Any doubts ask me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the function rather than binding the function.
bind function like this :

```
 $("#registar").on("click",opc);
 $("#entrar").on("click",opc);
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't knew the .on("click",) existed.

Answer (score 1):

You want to pass the function `opc` to the `.click()` method, but when you say `.click(opc())` you're not actually passing the function, you're calling the `opc` function immediately and passing *what it returns* to `.click()`.

Do this instead:

```
$("#registar").click(opc);
$("#entrar").click(opc);
```

Comment: Thank you! I was really stuck there.